# Create or replace role?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, roles

How do you create or replace a role (that might or might not exist) in Oracle? For example, the following does not work:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE ROLE role_name;
  GRANT SELECT ON SCM1_VIEW_OBJECT_VW TO role_name;
```

Any way to do this without PL/SQL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Solution**

A combination of the given answers and a pragma control accomplishes this task for Oracle 10g.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE create_role( role_name IN VARCHAR2 ) IS
PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE ROLE '||role_name;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    -- ORA-01921: If The role name exists, ignore the error.
    IF SQLCODE <> -01921 THEN
      RAISE;
    END IF;
END create_role;
```

**Test**

This sequence works:

```
DROP ROLE role_name;
CREATE ROLE role_name;
CALL create_role( 'role_name' );
CALL create_role( 'role_name' );
```

The final create role statement fails, as expected:

```
DROP ROLE role_name;
CALL create_role( 'role_name' );
CREATE ROLE role_name;
```

Comment: As a general rule I wouldn't put DDL inside a function, you should convert this to a procedure.  Second I really don't see what the autonomous_transaction is for - you don't have a DML transaction.

Comment: Creating a role from inside a function that is called from a SQL statement seems like a really bad idea. Care to explain why you need that?

Comment: Still does not show why you couldn't use a procedure. If you want to call it from SQL, you can just use "EXEC create_role('role_name')". Of simply "create_role('role_name')" if you call it from PL/SQL.

Answer (score 5):

Best practice is to attempt the creation of the role, then handle the appropriate exception gracefully if it occurs; this means you don't need to run potentially expensive data dictionary queries:

```
begin
  execute immediate 'create role role_name';
exception
  when others then
    --"ORA-01921: role name 'x' conflicts with another user or role name"
    if sqlcode = -01921 then 
      null;
    else
      raise;
    end if;
end;
```

And yes, you need PL/SQL to do this - it's the best tool for this job, anyway.

Comment: FOUT in regel 2:
.ORA-06550: line 2, column 3:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CREATE" when expecting one of the following: ...

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE
  v_dummy NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT 1
  INTO v_dummy
  FROM dba_roles
  WHERE role = 'MY_ROLE_NAME';
EXCEPTION
  WHEN no_data_found THEN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE ROLE my_role_name';
END;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no syntax for "create or replace" for roles.  Not sure of your version of Oracle but this hasn't changed much that I can recall. http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6012.htm

You can grant select to the role multiple times and it will accept the grant every time provided the role exists.

You could do an anonymous block and ignore the execption if the role already exists or something else where you see if the role exists by querying DBA_ROLES.